# Log-likelihood of the normal distribution.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

On the attached picture I've highlighted the term which I do not agree with. Is it actually true ? In my calculations I get $$-n(\frac{1}{2}\log(\sqrt{2\pi})+\log(\sigma)),$$
instead. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Notice that $0.5 \log(\sigma^2)=\log(\sigma)$. So $\sigma$ terms coincide. $\log \pi$ is often omitted because this is a constant not affecting anything. But formally speaking you are correct.Nevertheless log-likelihood is often claimed to be defined up to constant addend.